# Store images from assets folder to database and retrive it to image view

Tags: android, database, assets

Can any one tell me how to Store images from assets folder ie(assets/pictures/filename) to database and retrive it to image view from database?I need this solution for my quiz app. Also i need to know whether i could see updated files on assets folder if i use database to get image to app?

Comment: Have u achieved this task solution can u please share with me

Comment: @ErumHannan No I haven't